# Can ViewPager and PagerAdapter be loaded permantly?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am using ViewPager and PagerAdapter in my app to display a fixed number of screens (about 6 more or less). Almost each time the user changes from one screen to the other then that screen is being loaded. The loading takes a bit sometimes and makes it to look slow.

So, is there any way to have all the pages loaded at the beginning and keep them in memory all the time?
In case Android needs memory it would be ok to free some pages (or all of them and reload them when necessary) but I just don't want to load every page every time. Any hint about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(10);` to store 10 pages simultaneously.